# Why you need to divide to calc conditional probability

Tags: probability

The definition of **P(A|B) = P(A AND B) / P(B)**, and it basically translates to "if B happens, what is the probability to A to happen", if this is correct then why simple **P(A|B) = P(A AND B)** isn't enough?

Thanks!